# Not able to set focus on next button after selection of row

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to query by dynamic web table through selenium. I was able to query and select a record based on the i/p of my excel file

```
WebElement mytable = driver.findElement(fetchObject(sObjectName));
List<WebElement> rows_table = mytable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
int rows_count = rows_table.size();

for (int row=0; row<rows_count; row++){
    List<WebElement> Columns_row = rows_table.get(row).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    int columns_count = Columns_row.size();
    for (int column=0; column<columns_count; column++)
    {
       WebElement radioBtn = driver.findElement(fetchObject(sValue));                            
       radioBtn.click();
       break;
    }
}
```

My code struck after selecting the radio button. I am not able to select the button on the page to navigate to my parent window.

```
Exceptions are captured after wait. 
Feb 24, 2018 6:02:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '500' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'timeout' (408 expected)
[ERROR] 2018-02-24 18:02:35.932 [main] DetailedLogs - Error : >>>>>Class Keywords | Method dynamic_webtable | Exception desc :Timed out waiting for page to load.

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: internet explorer, browserVersion: 11, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:ieOptions: {browserAttachTimeout: 0, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enablePersistentHover: true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.ensureCleanSession: true, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true, ignoreZoomSetting: false, initialBrowserUrl: http://localhost:41323/, nativeEvents: true, requireWindowFocus: false}, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore}
```

I am able to see my record gets clicked. Even I had put breaks after each for loop for Column & Row. 
I am running the code in IE11 Browser
Please suggest how this issue can resolve this issue

Comment: Check this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162835/selenium-not-detecting-the-second-window-in-ie/48220024#48220024

Comment: I tried setting the capabilities of IE browser. Still same issue

Comment: Where is `sValue` defined?  What is the returned value for `fetchObject(sValue)` ?

Comment: sValue:- locators specified in the excel. FetchObject Function is to pick the correct locator based on the value provided on the Excel